# Sequence of events on click of button

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am creating a virtual agent & I am using Python 2.7 libraries for that. Below is the snap shot of libraries for the reference

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
from wx import Bottom
from wx.tools.img2py import img2py
#import PIL
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx
import new
from time import gmtime, strftime
```

On click of a button 'Start Conversation', I am displaying an image followed by virtual agent greeting the customer. below is the code.

```
def Talk():
    global FirstCall
    global canvas1
    global canvas2
    global panel
    canvas2.pack_forget()
    panel.pack_forget()
    image = Image.open("C:\Python27\Agent.gif")
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    canvas1.image = photo  # <--- keep reference of your image
    canvas1.create_image(0,0,anchor='nw',image=photo)
    canvas1.pack()

    if FirstCall == 0:
        CurTime = int(strftime("%H", gmtime()))
        if CurTime < 12:
            Say ("Hello, Good Morning")
        elif CurTime > 12 and CurTime < 16:
            Say ("Hello, Good Afternoon")
        else:
            Say ("Hello, Good Evening")
        FirstCall = 1
```

Below is how the button 'Talk' is involved :-

```
conversationbutton = Button(frame, text='Start Conversation', height=2,
                            width=40, bg="navy blue", fg="white",
                            font=("Arial", 10, "bold"), command=Talk)
conversationbutton.pack(side=BOTTOM, padx=7, pady=7)
```

Issue:

As per the sequence of code, the image should be displayed first & then greeting message ( good morning, afternoon or evening should come.

However the image is displayed **after** the greeting message.

Expected:

Image should get displayed first and then greeting message

Please can you suggest what could be the problem?

Comment: Please format your code correctly by copy-and-paste from the source code, then highlighting the code and clicking the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: Try adding a `canvas1.update_idletasks()` after the `canvas1.pack()` statement.

Comment: hi Martineau, thanks for your response. It resolved the issue partially. Let me explain it below.
When I open the VA, I display a welcome image. Code for which is as below

Comment: When i click the button ' Start Conversation', above shared code is triggered, which changes the image & greet the customer. Now the first problem is resolved i.e. on click of this button the new image & greeting is happening at the same time. However the previous image 'howcanihelp' is disappearing after good evening is said.

Existing order - 
Howcanihelpyouimage
Start Conversation button is clicked
Agent image is displayed on top of  Howcanihelpyouimage still appearing in background. Image & Greeting happens together
Howcanihelpyouimage disappears

Comment: Expected order - 
Howcanihelpyouimage
Start Conversation button is clicked
Just Agent image should be displayed. Howcanihelpyouimage should disappear

Below is the code

def Talk():
    global FirstCall    
    global canvas1
    global canvas2
    global panel
    canvas2.pack_forget()    
    panel.pack_forget()
    image = Image.open("C:\Python27\Agent.gif")
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    canvas1.image = photo  # <--- keep reference of your image
    canvas1.create_image(0,0,anchor='nw',image=photo)
    canvas1.pack()
    canvas1.update_idletasks()